# Neo.ClientError.Statement.ExternalResourceFailed

Tags: neo4j, cypher, load-csv

```
load csv with headers from 'file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/Neo4J'
as row 
Create (:State_Code {state_cd:row.st_cd})
```

**I have tried this code and it is throwing an error as:**

> Neo.ClientError.Statement.ExternalResourceFailed: Couldn't load the external resource at: file:/C:/Users/ssarse/Desktop/Neo4J

Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**By default, Neo4j doesn't allow loading data from file URLs. And if allowed it reads files from the import directory only.**

If you want to load files from other directories, you have to allow that in `neo4j.conf`

**You can easily configure this:**

1. Find the `neo4j.conf` file for your Neo4j installation. [Read here about file locations.](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/file-locations/)
2. Comment this line(By adding `#` in the start):

   ```
   dbms.directories.import=import
   ```
3. Uncomment this line to allow CSV  import from file URL:

   ```
   #dbms.security.allow_csv_import_from_file_urls=true
   ```
4. Restart Neo4j

Comment: Did that still the file is not accessable

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the file is clean and that you don't use the wrong extention; because in my experience not doing that can cause it to not be imported.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).