# Neo4j Desktop | Neo.ClientError.Statement.ExternalResourceFailed

Tags: neo4j-desktop

Here, I simply introduce my situation about configuration:
System: Windows 11
Neo4j Desktop Version: 1.4.15

when I had finished that imports csv file to the `C:\Users\ouyangkang\.Neo4jDesktop\relate-data\dbmss\dbms-00982ce7-0cb6-4ee7-b15a-1bc12ac5890e\import` direcotry. I clicked open button and run following command:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///film_name.csv' AS row MERGE (n:name {name: row.name, encoding: row.encoding});
```

I got a error:
`Couldn't load the external resource at: file:/C:/Users/ouyangkang/.Neo4jDesktop/relate-data/dbmss/dbms-00982ce7-0cb6-4ee7-b15a-1bc12ac5890e/import/film_name.csv`

And I saw a similar error solution in [Neo.ClientError.Statement.ExternalResourceFailed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56573653/neo-clienterror-statement-externalresourcefailed). I got a new error when configuration the neo4j.conf file
`Couldn't load the external resource at: file:/film_name.csv`
What's worse, I can't use the import function, it reminded that `Trying to open undefined directory`.

Please help me, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I finially found the error that it is the file format question. The Neo4j not can use all csv file. You need to convert the file to guaratee the file format is standardized csv file with seperating by ','